# Backing up an rsnapshot directory to a remote device

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot, hardlink

I have a local backup server that uses rsnapshot with hard links that contains about 10TBs of information which add about 4 to 5GBs per day. It's works great.  I've been requested to set up and maintain a remote backup of the local rsnapshot directory structure.  It's a nightly backup. I've tried using rsync with encryption which takes forever and eats system resources. A previous post says not to use rsync with hard links for that reason.  I need a suggestion of how I can keep the local and remote copies of the rsnapshot structures in sync?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for encryption?

Comment: I'm using hard drive encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a secondary rsnapshot instance, which only backups the current/daily snapshot of the primary rsnapshot instance. In addition to the obvious performance benefit, there is also an actual security benefit in the secondary rsnapshot maintaining its own history. That way any (silent) disk corruption on the primary rsnapshot instance won't overwrite all the history on the secondary instance.

Comment: ok, so what your saying is rsync only the current day, and week or month if it available?  Not the whole rsnapshot directory structure every night?